# matplotlib Dictionary containing the plot settings

Tags: python

I'm developing a class in order to produce plot suitable for my pourpose... at the first time I define the `*args` to be passed to the class in an easy way =

```
attribute = [*args]
for in in range(len(attribute)):
   plot(attribute[i],attribute[i+1], attribute[i+3])
```

where `args` was a list containing vector1, vector2 , label='for the legend')

Now I realize that some times I need to pass to the plot method of my class stype, more parameter then just a label .. for example the marker , the particular colours ... the line width and so I Think to pass as thirds-th argument a dictionary to be unpacked in this way :

```
for i in range(0,len(self.variable)-1,3):
            plt.plot(self.variable[i],self.variable[i+1],self.variable[i+2])
```

but I have really not idea of how to pass this dictionary .. I try with :

```
fig1.plot(fet,feu[:,0],{ 'label' : 'Explicit Euler', 'linetype' :'-'},bet,beu[:,0],'Implicit Euler', {}, cnt,cnu[:,0], { 'label' : 'Crank-Nicholson'} )
```

**EDIT** thanks guys but I'm solved :

```
 for i in range(0,len(self.variable)-1,3):
            plt.plot(self.variable[i],self.variable[i+1],**self.variable[i+2], linewidth=3)
```